# Share authentication between ASP.NET and Wordpress

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress

We are using Forms Authentication on the ASP.NET pages and we would like to share the login state to WordPress, i.e. if somebody logs to the ASP.NET pages he will be also able to access Wordpress pages without another login.

We have found a few tips about the security:

1. Solution from Palantir - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1421127/2066007). It seems interesting but I have no idea which functions in Wordpress has to be overwritten - do you have any idea?
2. Working solution which we now use - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4411545/2066007). However credentials are passed in POST so they are visible to client. The way how to secure this is to use some encryption/decryption algorithm. If anybody needs help with the implementation, please ask.
3. IIS authentication plugin - [link](http://mvolo.com/iis-authentication-plugin-for-the-wordpress-php-blogging-engine/). It seems that due to the changes in the WP code, it is no longer valid

Has anyone been able to implement any working solution which allows you to share the authentication between ASP.NET and WordPress pages?